# Remove Lines From First File Contained In Second File

Tags: python, file

So I have 2 files, `file1` and `file2`, of unequal size and at least a million `return separated` lines each. I want to match content from `file1` with `file2` and if a match exists, remove the same from `file1`. Example:

```
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| file1      | file2     | after processing - file1 |
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| google.com | in.com    | google.com               |
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| apple.com  | quora.com | apple.com                |
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
| me.com     | apple.com |                          |
+------------+-----------+--------------------------+
```

My code looks viz.

```
with open(file2) as fin:
        exclude = set(line.rstrip() for line in fin)

for line in fileinput.input(file1, inplace=True):
        if line.rstrip() not in exclude:
            print
            line,
```

Which just deletes all contents of `file1`. How can I fix that?
Thanks.

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to keep at least one of those files in the working memory?

Comment: @zwer yes. 1 have 16 gigs. I think that must be enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `print` statement and its argument are on separate lines. Do `print line,` instead.

Comment: Damn! Will accept as soon as allowed. Python 2 is evil. Just used `print(line.rstrip())` and worked to perfection, please add the same.

Answer (score 0):

If the working memory is not a problem, I'd suggest a crude solution - load up `file2` and then iterate over the `file1` writing down the matching lines:

```
import os
import shutil

FILE1 = "file1"  # path to file1
FILE2 = "file2"  # path to file2

# first load up FILE2 in the memory
with open(FILE2, "r") as f:  # open FILE2 for reading
    file2_lines = {line.rstrip() for line in f}  # use a set for FILE2 for fast matching

# open FILE1 for reading and a FILE1.tmp file for writing
with open(FILE1, "r") as f_in, open(FILE1 + ".tmp", "w") as f_out:
    for line in f_in:  # loop through the FILE1 lines
        if line.rstrip() in file2_lines:  # match found, write to a temporary file
            f_out.write(line)

# finally, overwrite the FILE1 with temporary FILE1.tmp
os.remove(FILE1)
shutil.move(FILE1 + ".tmp", FILE1)
```

**EDIT**: Apparently, [`fileinput.input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) is doing pretty much the same so your problem was indeed a typo. Oh well, leaving the answer for posterity as this gives you more control over the whole process.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for [`fileinput.input(inplace=True)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input). His code is modifying `file1`.

Comment: @Robᵩ - Ha, I didn't know that. One learns something new each day. I've updated my answer accordingly.